# form_for with a namespaced resource with a many to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, many-to-many, form-for

I'm getting stuck getting a form_for to work with a namespaced resource that has a many to many relationship I need to reference in the form.

The relationship is stretches impact many body areas and body areas can have many stretches.

Here's the resource:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :stretches, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  resources :body_areas, only: [:new, :create]
end
```

Here's the form_for:

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @stretch, @body_area] do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.label :body_area_id %>
  <%= f.collection_select :body_area_id, BodyArea.all, :id, :name, prompt: 'Select a Body Area' %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

And my controller:

```
  def new
    @stretch = Stretch.new
    @body_area = BodyArea.all
  end
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method `to_key' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<BodyArea id: 1, name: "Legs 1">]>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions that could help me out? Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ActionView::Template::Error:    undefined method `to_key' for
>   ActiveRecord::Relation BodyArea id: 1, name: "Legs 1"

I believe the error is due to because of `@body_area = BodyArea.all`. It should be `@body_area = BodyArea.new`

```
def new
  @stretch = Stretch.new
  @body_area = BodyArea.new
end
```

However, as per your *routes*, your *form is wrong*. It seems like you are creating a *new Stretch*. If so, your form should look like this

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @stretch] do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.label :body_area_id %>
  <%= f.collection_select :body_area_id, BodyArea.all, :id, :name, prompt: 'Select a Body Area' %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not trying to make a new BodyArea though. I want to reference the list of body areas to select which one this stretch belongs to. When I don't include @body_area in the parameters of my form_for, my form doesn't know what I'm talking about in the dropdown menu.

Comment: @KristenSqueeMueller It knows, because you have `BodyArea.all` for the `collection_select`. You can remove `@body_area = BodyArea.new` as it is useless